# Countdown to a specific date & time in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

```
time = DateSerial(2020, 10, 13)
```

I can use `DateSerial` and a Do-While Loop in VBA to make a countdown to 13th October 2020 midnight with the above code. How can I make it countdown to 10 am on 13th October 2020?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add 10 hours using [`TimeSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timeserial-function):

```
time = DateSerial(2020, 10, 13) + TimeSerial(10, 0, 0)
```